# DirectShow.NET - webcam resolution property page

Tags: c#, directshow, directshow.net

I'm using DirectShow.Net to access my webcam. I want to display a property page for my webcam to set video capture resolution and FPS rate. I try this by using a sample demo code from DirectShow.NET samples - DxPropPages. [Here](http://pastebin.com/f7888a2a4) is the code. However second tab in property window is disabled.

I need this tab to be enabled so user can set a caputre resolution. How I can achieve that? I'm new to DirecShow and don't really know what to change is this demo code.

PS I wanted to post some screenshots to show you what I mean, but I can't since I'm new user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the resolution using the [IAMStreamConfig](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd319784(VS.85).aspx) interface.
This way you can show your own UI and persist the setting. 
I don't have a specific sample in mind but I know the the net filled with code using it.
All other properties you see in the property pages can also be control (If the web cam supports it), [Take a look at this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407332(VS.85).aspx) page for video capture Interfaces all of them supported by DirectShow.NET.

Comment: Thanks! IAMStreamConfig is what I need.

Also I found answer for my original question:
http://sourceforge.net/forum/message.php?msg_id=5123929